# Получение ошибки “InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character”

Tags: javascript

доброго дня, уважаемые форумчане!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Имеется вот такой код:

```
var country  = document.createElement("<INPUT type=hidden name=country value=\""+butt.country+"\">");
```

Он выдает вот такую ошибку в хроме и мазиле:"InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid characte"

Причем в IE воспринимается нормально и работает как часы.

Слышал, что такое написание сейчас не пременимо для современных браузеров. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: неа, к сожалению не помогает

Comment: `butt.country` - на английском это звучит смешно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createElement` сперва создает элемент определенного типа и только потом ему нужно присваивать атрибуты. Попробуй

```
var el = document.createElement("INPUT");
el.type = "hidden";
el.name = "country";
el.value = butt.country;

document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ LblSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439509/176684) правильный и я тоже так рекомендую. Вот еще один вариянт:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<INPUT type=hidden name=country value=\"" + butt.country + "\">";
document.body.children[document.body.children.length - 1];
```

Comment: И Вам спасибо :) Воспользовался правда вариантом выше :)

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же ошибка, когда я пытался создать компонент с имененм EmailValidate и пробовал настроить роутинг. Переименование компонента в EmailValidatePage решило проблему.

Похоже, что для компонентов с определёнными суффиксами не могут быть настроены маршруты, что вообще говоря странно.

Использовал react версии 16.13